Is the 7809 bad for a DC motor?
I have a small 12V, 3S1P pack of 18650 cells. I am trying to power a 9V motor, but when I turn it ON the motor becomes very unstable, it spins, keeps running slow, then slows down, sometimes it does not even spin at all. The voltage goes between 0.4 V to 8.99V. I don't know if a DC motor is incompatible with this type of 7809 regulator.
The motor consumes approximately 510ma when directly powered by a 9V power supply.
This is more or less what I have:

A 12V battery passes through a 2 ampere fuse to an ON/OFF switch. When it is activated, it gives power to a 5V to 12V charger through step up of that module. The switch is so that it does not consume anything when the motor is not used since they have very low consumption. From there it goes to the 7809 regulator which, measuring GND and the OUTPUT, does give me 9V, but when turned on, it becomes unstable voltage. I tried with a 12V light bulb and it kept the 9V at the output, turning on the light weakly without flickering.
If the regulator is incompatible, which regulator do you suggest? This regulator has a small heatsink.  The anomaly starts immediately when I turn the switch on, so heat is not the issue.

Have you read the datasheet for the 7809? You’re missing some capacitors.

The 7809 probably overheats and goed into thermal shutdown. It also misses capacitors for stabilization. These are not optional (see @kruemi's answer).

I think the whole setup will go perfectly well without 7809.


You left out the capacitors that the LM7809 datasheet specifies.
Three 18650 cells in series is anywhere from 7.5V (fully discharged) to 12.6V (fully charged.)  The normal operating voltage is 3.7V per cell, so 11.1V for your three cells in series.
The dropout voltage of the LM7809 is 2V.  That is to say, the input voltage has to be at least 2V higher than the output voltage.
Assuming 12.6V and 510mA, your LM7809 will have to dissipate (12.6-9)*0.510 = 1.8 watts of power.
The LM7809 will automatically reduce output voltage and current when overloaded.
The regulator won't work when the battery voltage drops below 11V (3.7V per cell.)


Put in the recommended capacitors.
Use a larger heatsink.  The built-in tab of the regulator is not adequate.
Add one more cell to the battery (four cells in series.)  That will let you make full use of the battery charge.


You might find it better to use a switching power supply for your motor.

Lower losses.
No heat sink.
Lower dropout so that you don't need to raise the battery voltage.

If you go with a switching power supply, make sure it can handle the stall current of your motor.

Another option is to pulse-width-modulate the motor current.  Although it may seem counter-intuitive, using a full h-bridge driver and reversing the polarity of the motor voltage can actually be a good way to do things if one can manage a switching frequency which is fast enough relative to the motor inductance (and can be a very bad way of driving things if the frequency is below that).

Many motor controllers effectively act like switching power supplies, except that the motor's inductance is used instead of an external inductor.

Several issues here, some of which can be solved by reading the datasheet of the exact type of 7809 you're using.

The text of the datasheet will also say that those capacitors should be as close as possible to the 7809.
You're using a 3S cell which (probably) has an output voltage between 9.6V an 12.6V. Most 78xx series devices need about 2V of voltage drop to work reliably (LDO variants going a bit lower.) At the lower end your linear regulator won't work reliably. At the high end you have a voltage drop of 3.6V which at 500mA means you've got 1.8W that are converted into heat in the 7809. Lucky for you, you'll only burn your fingers on the case because the 7809 shuts down if it gets too hot. You need to mount the 7809 on a heatsink.
DC-motors have a much higher turn on current. Most 7809 will clamp the current at 1.5 amperes by reducing the output voltage. This could be the reason for the erratic behaviour you see on the motor.
You'll need to add a way to handle the noise from the DC motor (again, a capacitor can help there but also provide a free running diode.)
This is a very simplified circuit that could work:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

The 7809 itself is fine for a DC motor, but with caveats.
Input and output capacitors are needed for the 7809, but for your application, their absence would not make a difference significant enough to explain such wide excursions of output voltage.
Your input voltage to the 7809 needs to be (approx) 12V+. If it is less than than, the 7809 output won't be in regulation. It would still exist, but it might not hold up well to any load drawing current or start behaving strangely.
The 7809 can handle 1A of current with a heat sink. For short periods of time, 1A is fine without the heat sink as well.
Here's where I think you should check for your problem:

Check the data sheet of your particular 7809 manufacturer if you can, or the generic one. Measure input voltage with a DMM. Ensure the input to the 7809 is more than the minimum required for regulation.

DC motors take a lot more current at startup than they do when running. If you're expecting 500mA in steady state, then 2A of stall current at startup is not out of the question. An oscilloscope with current probe is one way to check for that. If this were happening, the 7805 may not be able to provide that much current, especially without bulky input and output caps to help (10s or 100s of uF). If the 2A fuse is resettable, ensure it isn't getting blown and reset. Though note that the fuse changes will happen over longer timescales, few seconds / minutes, and not a rapid on/off, so it might not be your issue from the description you've given.

I'm not sure what your 5V - 12V charger / step up is doing and how it is connected, but if it's in the supply path providing energy to the motor, I'd suspect the problem is more likely there than in the 7809. Ensure it has enough of a current rating. You may want a bulk capacitor on its output, at the very least. Additionally, switching supplies do sometimes need supply sequencing. If the motor starts demanding energy before the convertor is ready, it might not stabilise easily. Coupled with the high stall current requirements, you may be seeing some kind of reset loop in the switching converter.


